# Workbook.FollowHyperlink opens an ok/cancel dialog window

Tags: vba, excel

I am downloading/opening an excel file with the Workbook.FollowHyperlink method.

The problem is that I want to automatize the process but the method opens a dialog ok/cancel telling me that this file might harm my computer and if I really want to open it.

**CODE**

```
Dim strURL As String
strURL = "https://app1.intra.corp/A997/EnCours/Configs?Download=Exporter"
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (strURL)
```

I searched and tried a lot of things to get around without any success.

I tried:

1. Adding the registry entry to disable hyperlink warning for office.
2. Going in excel options, privacy setting and disabling the entrusted website protection or whatever it is called.
3. Using Application.SendKeys and trying to send "enter" to answer the dialog.
4. `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. (It works for every other dialog box except this one)
5. Adding the website to my trusted website list in Internet Explorer options (Note: I wasn't able to do this because these settings are locked by my company)

Comment: Have you tried `Workbooks.Open("https://app1.intra.corp/A997/EnCours/Configs?Download=Exporter")` instead?

Comment: You are the savior I needed! Thank you so much. I wasn't able to find this anywhere else on google. I'll let you make the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Workbooks.Open("https://app1.intra.corp/A997/EnCours/Configs‌​?Download=Exporter")
```

instead? That should work.